# Spyne/RPClib - How to respond with ComplexModel?

Tags: python, django, soap, wsdl, xmlrpclib

I'm using [SPYNE](https://github.com/arskom/spyne) for the very first time and I'm a little bit confused of how to respond with my ComplexModel.

```
#service.py
class Status(ComplexModel):
    statusCode = Integer
    statusMsg = String

class ResponseData(ComplexModel):
    status = Array(Status)
    version = Integer

class SoapService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(String, _returns=ResponseData)
    def doSomething(ctx, name):
        # ...
        # do something to get a django-model-object
        obj_data = Servers.objects.get(host=name)
        # put vars from the django-model-object into 'ResponseData' and nested 'Status'
        # e.g. statusCode = 1, statusMsg = 'online', version = 1

        """ experimental - status is not returned - version is 1:
        obj_status = Status()
        obj_status.statusCode = 1
        obj_status.statusMsg = 'online'

        retval = ResponseData()
        retval.status = obj_status
        retval.version = 1
        """
        return retval
```

Does anybody got an idea of how to fill the ComplexModels? The [docs](http://arskom.github.com/spyne/) and [examples](https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples) couldn't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution. Here a small demo.

```
#service.py
class Status(ComplexModel):
    statusCode = Integer
    statusMsg = String

class ResponseData(ComplexModel):
    status = Array(Status)
    version = Integer

class SoapService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(String, _returns=ResponseData)
    def doSomething(ctx, name):

        obj_data = Servers.objects.get(host=name)
        if obj_data.status:
            my_statusCode = 1
            my_statusMsg = 'online'
        else:
            my_statusCode = 0
            my_statusMsg = 'offline'

        retval = ResponseData()
        retval.status = [{'statusCode': my_statusCode, 'statusMsg': my_statusMsg}]
        retval.version = 1
        return retval
```

Comment: Well, you either fix it like you did, or you just drop the array, so ResponseData will have: status = Status
I think either should work, and in your example, you're not seems to be using the array

Comment: indeed, it is one possible solution. In the meantime I found some more. Almost forgot about this Q/A - it's over a year old :)